# Arithmetic overflow problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, types

i have a table in my database as freespace... it has a column called freesize with its datatype as int.

i have three valuse in it :

> 1065189988
>
> 1073741818
>
> 1073741819

now i try to get the total free space but i get an error.

```
private void GetFreeSpace()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SumooHAgentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(freesize)* 0.000000000931322575 as freespace from freespace", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        connection.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
          double  freeSpace = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["freespace"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

```
Line 123:            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(freesize)* 0.000000000931322575 as freespace from freespace", connection);
Line 124:            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
Line 125:            **sqlDa.Fill(dt);** here i get error
Line 126:            connection.Close();
Line 127:            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Any suggestions of how to get the value in freespace without changing the datatype?

Thanks

I know it works good with bigint, but I want int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're summing 3 large integers, then multiplying by a tiny double, but still want the output to be an int?

you could retrieve each row as an int, then do your math in c#

or you could cast the int to a bigint or double before the sum, so you don't overflow there.

Comment: yea getting them one by one is good... but then if there are more than three entries it will make the process slow...

Comment: @ Steven then what should i use instead??

Comment: If you're trying to calculate the size in GB, I would divide by 1024^3 instead and store the result in a `System.Decimal`.  More accurate that way and possibly more efficient.

Comment: @unknown: The original answer suggested bigint, which would work fine on the database side.  On the C# side, long is a 64-bit int.  Or if you're dealing with huge numbers but don't want rounding errors when representing decimal values, use Decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two choices as far as I can tell:  use Li0liQ's approach, something on the order of

```
SELECT SUM(freesize * 0.000000931322575) ...
```

which may suck because of accuracy concerns; or, sucking it up and using a bigint.  That raises the question:  why are you so concerned with using an int rather than a bigint?  If all you have is a hammer, then go nuts.  But I'd at least consider using bigint if there isn't a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the 3 values alone are larger than the data type size for an Int in SQL which is defined as the range:
    -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)

As such you could do the following:

```
select cast(sum(cast(freesize as bigint))* 0.000000000931322575 as int) as freespace from freespace
```

Which will support the math and get you back the result as an INT but this cast will just truncate the value and return 2 while as a double it would be 2.99 so you would also want to have SQL round the number appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by C < 1, and then sum.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply first, then SUM?

```
select cast(sum(freesize* 0.000000000931322575) as int)...
```

However, as Adam Gritt pointed out, do you want 2 or 3 as your answer: round or truncate? So, expanding on is answer... To round correctly as deal with truncation, add 0.5 before the cast back to int

```
select cast(sum(freesize* 0.000000000931322575) + 0.5 as int)...
```